# Lion Preview window stuck as always on top

Tags: macos, preview

After accidentally pressing some wrong keys, it seems my Preview window is stuck in 'Always on Top' mode.  I can't figure out how to undo this.  Is anyone aware of what might have happened?

edit: Well I just closed the document and re-opened it, and it seems to be behaving normally now.  Still curious as to what happened though.

Comment: I encountered the same issue recently, no clue what's going on there.

Comment: Have you by accident entered full-screen mode?

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me in Lion as well, but only with big PDFs. Closing and reopening fixes it.